Does LEM imply UIP in intensional type theory?
Does Hedberg's theorem hold in intensional type theory, where function extensionality is not assumed?
In HOTT book the proof follows from the fact that
$$\neg \neg x=y,$$
is a mere proposition. Indeed if $f,g:\neg \neg x=y$, assuming $z:\neg x=y$, then $fz=gz$ follows by contradiction. We may conclude $f=g$, but only using function extensionality.
EDIT: The theorem seems to hold in COQ, which is intensional. I could not find the proof.

Hedberg's theorem does not say that "LEM implies UIP". LEM holds and UIP fails in the simplicial set model.

What does "UIP" stand for?

@RobArthan: UIP = "Uniqueness of Identity Proofs".
